# Process Builder Create Record Action is missing few Fields to update

Tags: process-builder, translation, order-of-execution, create-records

I have a simple requirement to create Tasks based on 6 check box fields in a Custom Object( One Task per field is value is set to True). Since Process Builder gives the option to Create Records without writing Code, I created Processes using Process Builder to achieve the Requirement.

Also, since any number of fields can get updated in one session, I had to build 6 different processes that are based on same object.
In Criteria, i check for the specific field and if true, create a new Task by setting 5 different fields.

When i created the first one and tested, it worked fine and sets all the fields correctly. In Task I am updating the Template field which in turns set few other fields like Description/Impact/Urgency/Description/Status.

I went ahead and created 5 other processes using similar approach and tested them individually and they all work fine.

Now when i test them together( like update more than one check Box field), one one Task gets created will all fields updated.Rest Tasks miss some fields and mostly the Template field.

Any idea why Process Builder is not behaving properly when more than one process on same object is running.

Thanks,
Amitabh

Answer (score 1):

You need to put all your criteria in a single process.  And there is a new option in Process Builder **to evaluate a record multiple times in a single transaction** i.e, you can choose to evaluate all your 6 criteria within that same process. You do not need 6 different processes.

In your first criteria, if you click on **STOP**, there is an option to **continue evaluating next criteria**. So, even if the 2nd criteria falls under the "false" of 1st criteria, the process continues on to the next criteria and evaluates and runs it too, all with in a transaction.

This way you can also define the order of execution of these 6 criteria with in a transaction.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_advanced_reevaluate.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create single process with 6 actions to create Task.

If you create 6 Process on same object, there is no way to decided sequence of execution that which process will run first. You are saying that when its run individually it is working fine. Give it a shot to have a single process and six conditions with six actions.

Comment: Hi Jitendra, I thought of that option too but the way process builder works and the requirement i have dont allow me to create a single process with 6 actions.  The issue is process builder works more in a mutually exclusive scenario ( like if for  certain field or a combination of fields if specific action has to be done when they meet a scenario criteria's can be set in process builder). In my requirement, based on what fields are set, i need new unique records to be created depending on what filed is selected.